# How to run an external link in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, magento, server

Currently I have page say page1.php. Now in a certain event, I just want to run another link say http://example.com without actually refreshing this page. The link is a kind of script which updates my database. I tried using shell_exec('php '.$url); where $url='http://example.com' however it showed me an error that could not open file so I suppose shell_exec works only for internal files present on the server. Is there a way to do this directly or I have to go with AJAX? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by 'running the page'?

Comment: That page can be said as an API which doesn't require any parameters, so in short without actually refreshing this page, I just want to run or call or execute another page

Comment: Look at `include` or `require`

Comment: Add your script in a controller or model, to communicate with database. Call them when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using curl to send the request to the server with php.

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Alternatively you could try `file_get_contents`

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

Comment: I think this will be the ideal solution however it still didn't work. The url I am trying to call (http://example.com) stores cookies, so does that make a difference?

Comment: It should not matter. What does not work about this? Do you receive an error?

Comment: @user3103915 I've added an alternative could you try that one?

Comment: It worked just fine after adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_name); ... Thanks a lot !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this front-end and [I would use JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP): much clean and safer IMHO.